# ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL) while sending email oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, ora-24247

i have done all the activity i.e mention below, please tell which step / activity i am missing.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
                                    acl         => 'apex_user.xml',
                                    description => 'access to apex email',
                                    principal   => 'DBUSER',
                                    is_grant    => TRUE,
                                    privilege   => 'connect',
                                    start_date  => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                                    end_date    =>Null
                                    );
 COMMIT;
 END; 
  BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
                                        acl       => 'apex_user.xml',
                                       principal => 'DBUSER',
                                       is_grant  => true,
                                       privilege => 'resolve'
                                       );

 COMMIT;
 END;

   BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(
                                    acl         => 'apex_user.xml',
                                    host        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                                    lower_port  =>587,
                                    upper_port  =>587
                                    );
COMMIT;
 END;
```

to make sure the user can access the smtp packages, Run as SYS

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_TCP  TO DBUSER;
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_SMTP TO DBUSER;
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_MAIL TO DBUSER;
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_http TO DBUSER;
```

Enabling UTL_MAIL

```
alter system set smtp_out_server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587' scope = both;
```

Once i execute following query in Oracle since fistname.lastname@gmail.com having less secure app as true from google account

```
begin
  utl_mail.send(
  sender     => 'fistname.lastname@gmail.com',
  recipients => 'fistname.lastname@gmail.com',
  message    => 'Hello World'
   );
end;
```

> Error report -
>   ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

and give error once call from apex as

```
APEX_MAIL.SEND( 
    p_to => 'fistname.lastname@gmail.com', 
    p_from => 'fistname.lastname@gmail.com', 
    p_subj => 'APEX_MAIL with attachment', 
    p_body => 'Please review the attachment.', 
    p_body_html => '<b>Please</b> review the attachment');
```

> ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

however i tried using utl_smtp and again same error

```
create or replace PROCEDURE send_email(p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 587)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);
  UTL_SMTP.data(l_mail_conn, p_message  || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
```

> ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. c13sm6735648wrb.38 - gsmtp

please tell which command or anything misisng..

Comment: If you're just using utl_mail or apex_mail you don't need grants for utl_tcp or utl_smtp.

Comment: Your issue here is that utl_mail and apex_mail don't support TLS so this won't work directly with google's mail server which requires it. There are some options described if you google "utl_smtp ssl" which might work but they require using utl_smtp, e.g. http://oracle.ninja/sending-secure-e-mails-out-of-the-database-ssltls-utl_smtp-openssl-acl-wallet/

Comment: Is there a reason you're set on using gmail as your mail gateway?

Answer (score 3):

*You don't need any `commit`, since explicit DML operations are not performed for these operations. And using `begin..end` blocks not needed for every method invoking, either.*

*Your issue stems from the fact the neccessity of invoking  `Dbms_Network_Acl_Admin.Add_Privilege` method with `privilege => 'connect'` option also. So you can use the following :*

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
                                    acl         => 'apex_user.xml',
                                    description => 'access to apex email',
                                    principal   => 'DBUSER',
                                    is_grant    => TRUE,
                                    privilege   => 'connect',
                                    start_date  => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                                    end_date    =>Null
                                    );
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
                                       acl       => 'apex_user.xml',
                                       principal => 'DBUSER',
                                       is_grant  => true,
                                       privilege => 'connect'
                                       );

  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
                                       acl       => 'apex_user.xml',
                                       principal => 'DBUSER',
                                       is_grant  => true,
                                       privilege => 'resolve'
                                       );


  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(
                                    acl         => 'apex_user.xml',
                                    host        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                                    lower_port  =>587,
                                    upper_port  =>587
                                    );
 END;
```

With the following query all privileged accesses could be checked ( *through SYS or SYSTEM schemas* ):

```
select a.host,p.*
  from dba_network_acl_privileges p
  join dba_network_acls a on a.aclid = p.aclid
 order by a.host, p.principal, p.privilege;
```

Comment: Note, these APIs are deprecated from 12c, and we should now be using https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_networkacl_adm.htm#ARPLS74575

Answer (score 0):

1) IMHO smtp.gmail.com requires secured connection and authentication but package `utl_mail` is not supporting these functions. You can achieve this with utl_smtp.

2)  The Apex_mail package run with the privileges of their definer (apex_scheama) and your acl list is defined  for dbuser. Also here you have somehow  do the smtp authentication .