# ORACLE-APEX 18.2 ORACLE XE 11g Keycloak Oauth2 - problem with ACL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, keycloak, ora-24247

currently I am developing an application based on Oracle ApplicationExpress 18.2 connected with (only for dev) Oracle 11g XE.
One of requirements is to connect apex app with keycloack as openid provider.
I configured my application (i was basing on this tutorial: http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2018/06/facebook-google-and-custom.html ) to connect with keycloak.
The problem is: i am able to sign in (in keycloack i see new session and it is active) but apex is showing error page after redirect from keycloak. In debug log from apex i  see that error: 
- ora_sqlerrm:

> `ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line
>   1130 ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)`

What am i doing wrong? Of cource i added some ACLs by calling oracle procedures but it doesnt work.

Result of the query `select * from dba_network_acls;` in attachment *Query Result:*

[image]

Really looking forward for any help from You.

Regards,

Cezary

Comment: you might have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776888/ora-24247-network-access-denied-by-access-control-list-acl-while-sending-emai/53778348#53778348

Comment: thank you very much. 'ACL list' was exactly my issue. What's more: i had to add ACL for user 'apex_180200' - it was default user for database (as i was creating a sample project at first).
Problem solved.

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: Note, those particular APIs are deprecated from 12c, and we should now be using https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_networkacl_adm.htm#ARPLS74575