# Getting an 'ORA-53203: security violation' when attempting to test HTTP connection

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql

I've been trying to get Oracle to call a REST API. While getting things set up and running we ran into an issue where our code generates an ORA-53203: security violation. In the process of isolating the issue we set up a procedure to test the connection and this, too, generates the same error.

We are using Oracle 12c and we've set up ACE/ACL entries for the host we're testing with for both 'connect' and 'resolve' permissions.

```sql
create or replace procedure showTitleTag ( i_url in varchar2 )
AS
    l_httpreq   UTL_HTTP.req;
    l_httpresp  UTL_HTTP.resp;
    l_text      varchar2(32767);
    l_response  CLOB;
    l_title     varchar2(32767);
BEGIN

    l_httpreq   := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(i_url);
    l_httpresp  := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_httpreq);

    BEGIN
        LOOP
            UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_httpresp, l_text, 32766);
            l_response := l_response || l_text;
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
            UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_httpresp);
    END;

    l_title := REGEXP_REPLACE(l_response, '.*<title> ?(.+) ?</title>.*', '\1', 1, 1, 'in');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_title);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_httpresp);
        RAISE;
END;
```

This code, should give us the contents of the web-page's title tag (we used "http://www.redhat.com" as our test URL). Instead we receive the following errors:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-53203: security violation
ORA-06512: at "APPS.SHOWTITLETAG", line 29
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: I tried your code against redhat.com and it failed with a certificate error in my 12.1 database. I used http://www.foo.com and it worked - Returned "Foo.com"

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure [`the related access control list (ACL) assigned and the right privilege has been granted to your target host.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776888/ora-24247-network-access-denied-by-access-control-list-acl-while-sending-emai/53778348#53778348)
2. If there's no problem with the first, then look

   (`select a.lower_port, a.upper_port from dba_network_acls a where a.host like '%i_url%'`)

   whether you defined an interval for the ports of your `URL`, and
   contains the port of the target host(s).